# Latency spikes on outgoing requests from a cloud run service

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a node.js service running on CloudRun (docker image based on `node:14-alpine` - eu west1 region for cloud run and firebase rtdb) with an average load of ~1 req/sec. Some of the requests experience high latency (a few seconds) for outgoing http requests to Homegraph API or firebase realtime database.

The average latency is:

- <.21s - 50%
- < 1s - 95%
- < 2s - 99%

Things I've tried

- increasing the memory and the CPUs assigned to the service
- setting 1 instance always available (**Minimum number of instances**)
- using keepAlive in nodejs - this **does improve** things, but not that much
- creating a pool of firebase applications so each request has it's own app/db connection

What can/should I try next? Is there an issue with Cloud Run?

For example 1 sec call to homegraph:

[image: 7 sec call to homegraph]

Or a 4 sec call to firebase db (`getUserDeviceTraits`):

[image]

This is how a cold start looks (loading secrets, etc.):

[image: Cold start trace]

### Later edit (18 oct. 2021):

It simply solved itself out after a while and now it started happening again about a week ago. So after months where 99th was 1sec top and the average ~ 200msec, now the 99th has spikes of up to 12sec. Already tried updating all the dependencies (just in case). It's definitely not code related since I did no change in that period.

[image: And again]

Comment: How many request do you process in the sametime?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I set the concurrency limit to 100.

Comment: It's difficult to pin down what the issue is without having access to your project, that being said I would advise you to reach out to Cloud Support, you can find more information following this [link](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub).

Comment: And how is the real traffic? Can you try with a concurrency to 10?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I also tried with a concurrency of 10. It's the same issue. It has periods of time where there is high latency and after that it suddenly goes back to normal (with no changes in the average load/code/cpu/memory etc.)

Comment: A question to Google Cloud Support is better. I don't see why you have this behavior!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere it solved itself out after sometime and now it started happening again. I will try to get some support from Google Cloud